# Css transition - text fill from bottom

Tags: css, colors, transition

I have black text that I would like to make yellow on hover.

However I would like to transition to make the text fill the colour from the bottom to the top of the text.

Is possible with pure css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Store the same text in `data-*` attribute.
2. Place it on exactly above the text with `::before` or `::after` pseudo element.
3. Animate its height to `0` on hover.

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
  color: gold;
}

.text:before {
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.text:hover:before {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text" data-text="Some text here">Some text here</div>
```

Comment: I made a modification, so it will do all of this automatically. http://jsfiddle.net/3vfonq0j/4/