# CSS/SCSS fill text on hover, from bottom to top, with a gradient

Tags: css, animation, sass, linear-gradients

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673645/css-transition-text-fill-from-bottom) to be really helpful in trying to make an icon fill up on hover. I'm using fontawesome, so it's text that I'm filling. However, the solution offered by Mohammad it doesn't seem to be working with a gradient of color. Is there a work around? I am not allowed to use any js or framework.

[Here](https://codepen.io/alice-g/pen/wvPZvJa?editors=1100) is my attempt.

```
 .text {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  
  cursor: pointer; 
  margin: 20px;
  color: hotpink;
  // color: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,18,222,1) 0%, rgba(156,45,253,1) 100%);    not working
  
}

.text:before {
  transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.text:hover:before {
  height: 0;
}

<div class="text" data-text="ICON">ICON</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its good.

You may check https://animate.style/ this website for more animations with code.

Comment: It's not good, it doesn't work. // Thank you for the link. I'll keep it in mind, but it's a library, and aside from fontawesome, I'm not allowed one. :/